# Slow finishing when cat a large file of null content

Tags: bash, io, cat

The shell command:

```
truncate -s 1000000000 largefile
echo 'eof' >> largefile
cat largefile
```

Why the last command blocks for several seconds after `eof' being printed?

Comment: I tested it in Centos 6.4 with its terminal application(resides in System Tools).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cat` doesn't just block - it is very busy reading and writing one billion *zero bytes*.